# Combine .NET external dlls to a single executable file

Tags: c#, json, winforms, visual-studio, ilmerge

This is a simple question. I just can't run my program if the Newtonsoft.Json.dll is not in the program folder. Why this? I've tried adding the reference, added the file to the project root, added to the resources folder, but nothing worked. How to run the program without the Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the program folder? I'm developing in a Windows Form Application.

### UPDATE

Problem solved, thanks to **spender** for introducing me the [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge), a really really nice NuGet package that can combine third party dlls to a single executable binary file. For who wants to make a standalone application, just use ILMerge. Rapid, easy and extremely useful. See ya!

Comment: What's the problem with it being in the app folder? Did you want output of a single executable and *nothing* else?

Comment: Yes, a standalone app

Comment: Personally my favourite tool for embedding project dependencies is Fody Costura. It has minimal setup and integrates into the build. It compresses and packages up dependencies (managed, unmanaged and mixed-mode third-party assemblies as well as your own project outputs) as embedded resources allowing for single-file deployment if you play your cards right. https://github.com/Fody/Costura#readme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, if your program uses a DLL, then you'll need that DLL in the app folder (or in the user path, or the GAC).

The conventional method of distributing multiple files is with an installer. You can write one using either [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/) or the [VS Installer Projects](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx) extension. Now all your output files get installed in one go along with all the other goodness that comes with an installed program. I have a strong preference for this method.

However, there are alternatives:

- [Download the source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) and copy the source into your main project, then it will be compiled into your main assembly (make sure you check that this is permitted by the license).
- Use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to combine all your assemblies into a single binary.

Comment: @Hypister : Please consider a title change that is less tied to JSON.NET and more about the distribution of .net applications with external DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reference dll in your program, you can install it to GAC on client machine but I don't understand which the context you want

Comment: I would just like to run the program as a standalone. With dll compiled with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need some JSON serialization. Can you switch out your functionality with the `JavascriptSerializer` class which is installed with .Net?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: That would be very useful, but I need to use JSON.

Comment: that is what the JavascriptSerializer does... create and read JSON.  I see you have a solution using ILMerge, which is a great tool, but you may want to give this a try to avoid that extra build complexity and stick to base class libraries.  Hard to do once you have a working solution though :)

Comment: Thank you, but sooner or later I would need this tool. And when I went use the JavascriptSerializer I did not have the right references, so I gave up and opted for ILMerge.